# PHP contact form with dropdown to change e-mail

Tags: php, forms, email, contact-form

I am working on a contact form with a dropdown menu to select an e-mail address to a particular physician. I am working from a template and I do not have much experience in PHP. I got "Warning: Wrong parameter count for array_key_exists()" when I uploaded the form to the server, and I can't pinpoint the issue.

```
<link href="css/contactform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php

// Set email variables
$email_to = array('phys1' => 'phys1@xxxxxx.xxx', 'phys2' => 'phys2@xxxxxx.xxx');
if(array_key_exists($_POST['dropdown']))
{
$recipient = $emails[$_POST['dropdown']];
//send email to $recipient
}

$email_subject = 'Form submission';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('fullname','email','comment');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
'fullname' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.',
'comment' => 'Please enter your Message to continue.'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {
// Sanitise POST array
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

// Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
    // the field has been submitted?
    if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

    // check there is information in the field?
    if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

    // validate the email address supplied
    if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

// basic validation result
if(count($validation) == 0) {
    // Prepare our content string
    $email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

    // simple email content
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
    }

    // if validation passed ok then send the email
    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content);

    // Update form switch
    $form_complete = TRUE;
}
}

function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
   return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var nameError = '<?php echo $error_messages['fullname']; ?>';
    var emailError = '<?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?>';
    var commentError = '<?php echo $error_messages['comment']; ?>';
</script>

</head>
<div id="formWrap">
<div id="form">
<?php if($form_complete === FALSE): ?>
<form action="/contact.php" method="post" id="comments_form">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Name</div>
    <div class="input">
    <input type="text" id="fullname" class="detail" name="fullname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fullname'])? $_POST['fullname'] : ''; ?>" /><?php if(in_array('fullname', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['fullname']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="context"></div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Your E-mail</div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="email" value="
<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" />
<?php if(in_array('email', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="context"></div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Select Physician</div>
    <div class="input"><select name='dropdown' >
<option value=''>

    --Select--</option>
<option value='phys1'>

    phys1</option>
<option value='phys2'>

    phys2</option>
<option value='phys3'>

    phys3</option>
</select>       </div>
    <div class="context"></div>


    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">

     Your Message</div>
    <div class="input">
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="mess"><?php echo isset($_POST['comment'])? $_POST['comment'] : ''; ?></textarea><?php if(in_array('comment', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['comment']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="submit"></div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
</div>
</form>
<?php else: ?>
<p>

    Thank you for your message!</p>
 <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>  
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

The form is uploaded here: http://endotest.zxq.net/contact_test.php

Comment: `if(array_key_exists($_POST['dropdown']))` - doesn't it take two parameters?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), you'll notice that the function takes in two parameters. A key (the array key) and an array (the array that you want to search for the array key/index in question).

Your code:

```
if(array_key_exists($_POST['dropdown']))
```

is the issue. You probably meant:

```
if(array_key_exists($_POST['dropdown'], $emails))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `array_key_exists` with `isset` and see if that works for you

```
if(isset($_POST['dropdown']))
{
    $recipient = $emails[$_POST['dropdown']];
    //send email to $recipient
}
```

Comment: array_key_exists is often used to whitelist user input. Changing it to isset() may introduce a vulnerability.

Comment: Uhm... no. They work the same, with the only difference being that `isset` will return `false` if the key exists but has `NULL` as its value (which no `$_POST` will have)

Comment: If $_POST['dropdown'] exists as a variable, isset() will return TRUE. If isset() is introduced into the code above, you're still not certain that the value of $_POST['dropdown'] represents a valid key in the $emails array. `isset($emails[$_POST['dropdown']])` would work, not `isset($_POST['dropdown'])`